# Can the migration of this question be overturned?

Tags: support, migration

I asked [this](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/5466/do-computer-glasses-actually-work) question but realized the Biology community is a more appropriate place for it. My question is about the anatomy of the eye and that community seems more suitable. I did not recieve any answers on this site and decided to rephrase the question and ask it on biology.stackexchange instead.
However, my question was migrated back to this community ([link](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/5523/does-looking-at-monitors-fatigue-the-eye-muscles-and-or-affect-overall-fatigue)) so health.stackexchange now contains two questions who are basically the same. This also means I have undeserved reputation points.

Can this migration be overturned so [this](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/5523/does-looking-at-monitors-fatigue-the-eye-muscles-and-or-affect-overall-fatigue) question is back at biology.stackexchange? Or are there guidelines for asking questions I might not be aware of which prove this migration to be a good one?

Answer (score 3):

I talked with the Biology moderators, and they indicated that it wasn't really biology related since it didn't have anything really addressing the underlying biological mechanisms that would produce either the fatigue or degredation of the eyesight. I can close it here, which would reject the migration, however it would need to be edited to make it on topic for Biology.

Comment: I understand. I think the guidelines were not yet a 100% clear to me. Is it acceptable if I delete the migrated post? I don't think I can make it ontopic for Biology since I have minimal knowledge of anatomy

Comment: @Tom - Certainly. You can always delete your own question, no questions asked. (Pardon the pun. :p)

Comment: I must say that I think the original question was suitable for Bio. It was basically about accommodation.